# How to differentiate between x86 and x64 Operating Systems when Install my application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, installshield

I have an application, I finished it I created setup but I encountered a problem.

I have a few Prerequistes ( net framework4.5,Sql Server Express 2008 r2 ) I put both Sql Server Express 2008 r2 x64 and x32 in setup - I did this in the case the user does not have Internet Connection, but how do I know the client machine runs on x64 operating system, and how to make the application choose the good one.

Example: If client machine has x64 the setup should perform a silent install with the x64 version of Sql Server Express 2008 r2, and so on. Thank you

Comment: What installer system are you using?

Comment: InstallShield Limited Edition, Visual Studio 2013

Comment: look at this http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?184201-check-OS-32-or-64-bit

Comment: VersionNT64 property it seems what i'm looking for, but where to put it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [here](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-OS-dependent-install.html)

Install a component or run a custom action based on the Windows OS type (32-bit or 64-bit)
This can be done by using the VersionNT64 property in the "Condition" field for a component or the "Expression" field for a custom action.

If the component (or custom action) should be installed (or run) only on a 32-bit system, the condition is:

NOT VersionNT64
If the component (or custom action) should be installed (or run) only on a 64-bit system, the condition is:

VersionNT64